# CONCATE UNIQUE VALUES BASED ON ID IN INFORMAITCA

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

SCENARO/input,

```
COL1   COL2
100    ABC
101    PQR
100    ABC
100    OPQ
101    HDR
101    PQR
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
COL1   COL2
100    ABC,OPQ
101    PQR,HDR
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of classic string aggregation issue. Pls follow below steps.

1. using SRT order the data and get distinct. So, click enable distinct and then make sure you are ordering col1 first.
2. using expression transformation concat the COL2. Create 5 ports - in_out means input+output, in_ means input only, v_ means variable port and so on.

```
in_out_col1
in_col2
v_col2 = iif( in_out_col1=v_prev_col1, v_col2||',' ||in_col2,in_col2)
v_prev_col1 = in_out_col1
out_col2=v_col2
```

3. Create an AGG, group by col1. Create a new column max_col2 and assign the max value to it.

```
in_out_col1
in_col2
out_max_col2= MAX(in_col2)
```

4. Connect in_out_col1 to col1 and out_max_col2 to col2 for your desired data.

Comment: OUT_MAX_COL2 WHAT IT WILL DO

Comment: I NEED TO CONCAT UNIQUE VALUES BASED ON COL1

Comment: FOR EX,for 101 we have ABC,ABC,OPQ

Comment: BUT the output contain only ABC,OPQ

Comment: @bhagya Please keep in mind that ALL CAPS can come across as yelling online.

Comment: Then add distinct in sorter in the beginning to get unique values. I edited my answer.

Comment: Let me know if your problem is resolved?

Comment: problem is solved but other way i implemented.here i am concatinating two such cols  based on multiple key cols

Comment: May be  could you pls mark this closed/fixed and open a new one? If you have more keys, pls use all columns in place of col1.